# Фоновая картинка для ImageButton

Tags: android

Есть `Activity` с `ImageButton` у которого размеры 100dp на 100dp. Для экранов с диагональю 7 дюймов эта кнопка будет иметь размеры 200 на 200, а на экранах с диагональю 10 дюймов 300 на 300. Подскажите пожалуйста чтобы фоновая картинка четко отображалась на всех этих экранах какого размеры должна быть картинка для каждого из этих экранов? и Какое разрешение 300 или достаточно 72?

Comment: Подскажет кто-нибудь?

Comment: что вы понимаете под словом "четко"?

Comment: Чтобы картинка хорошо отображалась

Comment: Я сделал размеры картинок следующие:100,150,200,300 и 400. А кнопки решил сделать размеров 100×100, 150×150 и 200×200 соответственно

Comment: Осталось с фоном разобраться. Не понимаю пока каких размеров обычно делают фоновую картинку для самого приложения

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться вот этим калькулятором: http://angrytools.com/android/pixelcalc/